# Light up an LED on turning on circuit

Tags: led, dc, solenoid

I have a 12V DC power supply which would be connected with a solenoid and a manual button as shown in circuit diagram image below.

The rating of solenoid is from 9V-12.5V. It takes 500mA at 12V.

My requirement is to put an LED so that it lights up when the manual switch is turned on. I've basic understanding but that's it. Can I linearly put the LED light without causing any problems? Where should the LED be placed in the circuit if at all? Can off the shelf LED be used or some specific LED be used?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: You can't (generally) just put your LED in series with the solenoid.   It will melt.    LED's can't handle 500mA  (generally... expensive ones for flashlights etc. can but that's not what you want... You want an indicator).   What you wanna do then is put a series LED and resistor in PARALLEL to the solenoid.  Both current paths can share the same switch.   You probably ought also put a flyback diode across the solenoid (google "flyback diode")   Most 'indicator' LED's are 20mA devices, so use a 1k series resistor to keep it below max limit. Ebay "5mm LED", any will work, I suggest "diffuse".

Comment: @KyleB can you please share the circuit and add it as an answer? Yes flyback diode I'll be using, but LED + Resistor placement I'm really confused.

Comment: Sure brother, gimme a minute...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZE20b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D2 - I couldn't find a Schottky diode symbol.   Some folks would use a silicon diode here (i.e. 1N4001).   I prefer a Schottky because they're faster.   D1 can literally be any 3 or 5mm LED you find, they'll pretty much all have the same 20mA maximum.  Using a 1k resistor will keep the current well below 20mA so you'll have no issues there.

I suggest using a "diffuse" or "milky" LED instead of clear because they make better indicator lights  (i.e. if your intention is to look at the LED, use diffuse.  If your intention is to project light elsewhere, use clear).  So don't be fooled by brightness numbers - You don't really want something that blinds you if you look straight at it.  (Clear LED's have massively higher brightness specs, don't fall prey to that)

Note any color LED will work here, the 1k is universal enough of a value you won't have problems.  (That is NOT a universal statement... 1k is good enough HERE)